# Spark Ui not showing completed applications

Tags: apache-spark

Im using Spark standalone cluster and SparkUI is not showing completed applications though job ran successfully.please suggest

[image]

Comment: To view completed (finished) applications set up spark history server https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact

Comment: @RaphaelRoth i want to see Running & completed applications under 8080 port not in history server,i also set below properties still noluck

Answer (score 1):

Current screenshot is showing Spark Standalone Master UI. It shows links to SparkUI's of currently running applications/drivers and applications that were completed, though without the links.

In oder to see SparkUI's of completed applications, you need to have the following configuration in `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:///path/to/event-log-folder
spark.eventLog.dir file:///path/to/event-log-folder
```

and you also need to start `sbin/start-history-server.sh` as well to see the results. It *might* be used also for looking at running applications (as "show incomplete applications" link on it's UI), but on highly loaded Spark Master you'd get some delays and results will appear with delays.

Comment: usually http://<masterip>:8080/Json should show completedapps,activeapps etc.. right? ,even for this do I need to enable eventlogs and provide event log directory ?